# How to list columns/column types in Aginity

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm using Aginity Workbench for Netezza for the first time.

Does anyone know how to list columns and column types? The typical SQL code snippets I found online don't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just looking for a list of the columns and types for a given table, or are you looking to get it in column/row format to do something programmatic with it?

Answer (score 2):

This snippet should do what you want.

```
SELECT  
tablename,
   attname       AS COL_NAME,
   b.FORMAT_TYPE AS COL_TYPE,
   attnum        AS COL_NUM
FROM _v_table a
   JOIN _v_relation_column b
   ON a.objid   = b.objid
WHERE a.tablename = 'ATT_TEST'
AND a.schema = 'ADMIN'
ORDER BY attnum;

 TABLENAME |  COL_NAME   |       COL_TYPE       | COL_NUM
-----------+-------------+----------------------+---------
 ATT_TEST  | COL_INT     | INTEGER              |       1
 ATT_TEST  | COL_NUMERIC | NUMERIC(10,2)        |       2
 ATT_TEST  | COL_VARCHAR | CHARACTER VARYING(5) |       3
 ATT_TEST  | COL_DATE    | DATE                 |       4
(4 rows)
```

Comment: It could be worth noting that you will HAVE to caps (as ScottMcG is in his answer) when specifying the tablename/columns you're looking for.